# Azure: Same resource group for many VMs in DevTest labs

Tags: azure

Is it possible to create many VMs in a DevTest lab in the same Resource group? How can I do this?
A new resource group is created for each new VM ( with a random name) in the lab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to gather all DevTest Lab VMs into a single Resource Group.

This is the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/320373-devtest-labs/suggestions/15223317-gather-all-devtest-lab-vms-into-a-single-resource), Azure DevTest Labs Team has replied the issue, you could refer to it.

> We’ve planned the work to create minimum number of resource groups for lab VMs (starting from a single resource group for multiple lab VMs, and expand to another resource group if the resource quota is hit). Does it solve your problem? Providing naming convention for the lab-generated resource group and other resources is also planned.